# call a suspend function inside a normal function

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine, suspend, kotlin-coroutines

I want to call blocking a suspend function in a normal function, but does not block Thread to finishing suspend function and then return `Response`

```
override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {

    // getSession is a suspend function
    val session = sessionProvider.getSession()

    return chain.proceed(
        chain
            .request()
            .newBuilder()
            .addHeader("Authorization", "${session.token}")
            .build()
    )
}
```

Comment: You need to block the thread if you want to return value from your function. If you don't want to block you need to use callback function.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

This looks like you are implementing an OkHttp interceptor, so I am hoping that `intercept()` is being called on a background thread.

If so, [use `runBlocking()`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html):

```
override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {

    // getSession is a suspend function
    val session = runBlocking { sessionProvider.getSession() }

    return chain.proceed(
        chain
            .request()
            .newBuilder()
            .addHeader("Authorization", "${session.token}")
            .build()
    )
}
```

`runBlocking()` will execute the `suspend` function, blocking the current thread until that work is complete.

Comment: Would this cause issues because the return will be delayed and the intercept function is not marked as a suspend function?

Comment: @3366784: `runBlocking()` is not itself an `suspend` function, so from a compilation standpoint, everything should be fine. How well this works at runtime depends a lot on how well-behaved `sessionProvider.getSession()` is. If that takes a long time, every OkHttp request will take a long time, because the `runBlocking()` call is a blocking call, and `intercept()` will not proceed until `runBlocking()` completes.

Comment: Okay I understand it depends on `.getSession()`. I was confused because I know there are some languages that will kill your app if a regular function with return value take more than x seconds to return. But in this situation we are forced to delay the return and as you said this is okay. I tested this and added an extra delay and it didn't block the UI thread and didn't crash therefore it should be good.

Comment: @3366784 "languages that will kill your app if a regular function with return value take more than x seconds to return" - could you provide examples? I've never heard of that kind of language feature.

Comment: yeah Retrofit by default should run suspend api methods on its predefined background io dispatcher

Comment: i don't think that we should used runBlocking  in production app this is used for testing the app only.

Comment: @karan: I agree, it is the sort of thing that you should avoid where you can. However, in this case, until and unless OkHttp interceptors start to support `suspend fun` directly, you have little practical choice.

Comment: to avoid runBlocking  i have used CountDownLatch  

Example:-

GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
                        request = getToken(chain)
                        countDownLatch.countDown()
                    }
                    try {
                        countDownLatch.await(2000,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    }catch (_:Exception){
                    }

Comment: @karan: If your objective was the timeout, `withTimeout()` inside `runBlocking()` would be simpler.

Comment: @CommonsWare my Objective is not to use runBlocking instead you can use CountDownLatch