# Conflicting overloads when add suspend

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a working application, but I would like to improve one point. The method ("private fun save"), which is responsible for saving the information I need, I would like to make asynchronous.

But the problem is that when I change it to - "private suspend fun save", I have to make suspend and override fun intercept method. But since it is override, I get an error:

> Conflicting overloads: public open suspend fun intercept(chain:
> Interceptor.Chain): Response defined in
> com.pocketscout.network.PocketScoutInterceptor, public abstract fun
> intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain) : Response defined in
> okhttp3.Interceptor.

Is this problem somehow solved?

```
    class PocketScoutInterceptor(
    private val appContainer: PocketScoutContainer,
) : okhttp3.Interceptor {

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun intercept(chain: okhttp3.Interceptor.Chain): okhttp3.Response {
        val packet = buildPacket(timestamp, duration, request, response, description)

        save(packet)

        return response ?: okhttp3.Response.Builder().build()
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [call a suspend function inside a normal function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56409970/call-a-suspend-function-inside-a-normal-function)

Comment: @Sky I haven't seen this answer before, thanks! Only I do not fully understand how I can apply runBlocking in my code

Answer (score 0):

At this moment **OkHttp3** doesn't support `suspend` feature for interceptors. You can wrap `save` method

```
private suspend fun save(packet: Packet) { // Make suspend
   ...
}

runBlocking { save(packet) } // Call inside intercept
```

or all inside it:

```
private fun save(packet: Packet) = runBlocking {
   ...
}
```

Use this code at your own risk.

Comment: Thanks, but in this way I just block the stream, and I need to give the data from here to the repository

Comment: @Павел Hmm, you receiving stream from response?